# Text aligned right to percentage-sized image

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to achive this layout: on the left side an image, on the right side a text (in multiple paragraphs) which always uses the available horizontal space. The distance between image and text should always be 1em. I want the image to use as width a percentage (20%) of the horizontal space available, but it should never be less than 140px (min-width: 140px). Also, even if the text is longer in height than the image, it should keep its vertical line and should not float under the image.

Using two columns as in the code below does not work, because defining a minimal image width breaks the layout. Maybe the desired layout can be accomplished by using flexbox?

Note: using media queries is not an option for me.

```
*********  Lorem ipsum
* Image *  On the right, the text uses the
* Image *  available space.
* Image *  The text is made of multiple para-
* Image *  graphs. Important is, that even 
*********  if the text is longer in height
           than the image, it should keep its
           vertical line and should not float
           under the image.
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 140px;
}

.right p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima corporis voluptates
      <p>
        hfbvhjadfbv jsdfbjsdbfbjkvsvd hjfdbg sdbfhj dfhjb dfhjsbjhdv hdf
      </p>repellat ullam labore qui voluptatum error nesciunt ratione dolorem fugiat veritatis ipsum nobis eius dicta est obcaecati ab animi. Voluptatibus dolores natus sint enim fugiat. Sapiente voluptates enim officiis. Iste repudiandae illo nulla sed
      nam a ratione iure?</p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="group">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima corporis voluptates
      <p>
        hfbvhjadfbv jsdfbjsdbfbjkvsvd hjfdbg sdbfhj dfhjb dfhjsbjhdv hdf
      </p>repellat ullam labore qui voluptatum error nesciunt ratione dolorem fugiat veritatis ipsum nobis eius dicta est obcaecati ab animi. Voluptatibus dolores natus sint enim fugiat. Sapiente voluptates enim officiis. Iste repudiandae illo nulla sed
      nam a ratione iure?</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Apply the min-width to the column instead of the image; and remove width & float from the second column, and add `overflow:hidden` (that will prevent the text from going under the image.)

Comment: Thank you, this is it! Why not posting as an answer, so I can rate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to switch to a completely different technique such as flexbox, you can still fix this quite easily:

- apply the `min-width` to the column instead of the image
- remove `width` & `float` from the second column
- add `overflow:hidden` to the second column (that will prevent the text from going under the image)

The second part is important, because it allows the second column’s content to just take “the rest” of the available space - so that when due to the min-width the first column is not actually 25% percent wide, you don’t end up with more than 100% when the width of both columns is added together.